# SharedPreferences are not loading

Tags: java, android

I test the app on a physical device (Samsung Galaxy J4+).  I open it and enter data (destined for *SharedPreferences*). Then ...

*SharedPreferences* **do not load** when tapping the app icon after having made the app UI disappear using the "<" button at the bottom of my Samsung screen, but they **do load** when tapping the app icon after having made the app UI disappear using the "|||" or "O" button at the bottom of my Samsung screen. The latter leads me to conclude that the saving and loading method both work properly.

The **loading method** (importSavedData()) is embedded alright in the method onCreate(), inside the MainActivity class. There is no other *activity life cycle method* [onStart(), on Resume (), onPause () etc.] included in the app.

The **saving method** (saveData()) is invoked each time data is entered into the app (happens by pressing buttons), so I didn't deem it necessary to include that method in an onStop() or onDestroy() method. I did try switching between editor.apply() en editor.commit(), but to no avail.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int winnerA;
    int winnerB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       importSavedData();
    }

    public void importSavedData() {
       SharedPreferences savedData = getSharedPreferences("savedData", 
       Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           winnerA = savedData.getInt("winnerA_SP", 0);
           winnerB = savedData.getInt("winnerB_SP", 0);
    }

    public void saveData(){         
       SharedPreferences savedData = getSharedPreferences("savedData", 
       Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = savedData.edit();
           editor.putInt("winnerA_SP", winnerA);
           editor.putInt("winnerB_SP", winnerB);       
       editor.apply();
    }

    /* saveData() is executed when the user has changed
       the value of winnerA or winnerB by pressing one of the buttons in the 
       activity. */

 }
```

Comment: Include your code, that would help us troubleshoot your problem better.

Comment: user https://github.com/orhanobut/hawk

Comment: Is this your actual code? Is importSavedData() inside onCreate()????!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Override `onRestart()` and `onResume()` like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    importSavedData();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    importSavedData();
}
```

So that every time the app comes back, the values will be read from `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, because in the code the importSavedData() is indeed defined OUTSIDE onCreate(), as you suggest.

Comment: Then why in the code you posted it is INSIDE onCreate() and you also say: *The loading method (importSavedData()) is embedded alright in the method onCreate()*?

Comment: It is invoked inside onCreate(), not defined. If it can't even be invoked in onCreate(), how is onCreate() supposed to know that it needs to load the data?

Comment: Look carefully inside the code you posted.  importSavedData() is **defined** INSIDE onCreate().

Comment: I'm so sorry. You're right. I was looking at saveData() in stead of importSavedData(). I'll try defining importSavedData() outside of onCreate() right away!

Comment: I have adjusted the code in the app (and in my question). But the problem remains exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the app just goes into the background, it may not call `onDestroy`, which means that it won't call `onCreate` when it comes back. Put the loading in `onResume` to get it to load fresh every time the activity comes back into view. Take a look at the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle).

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    importSavedData();
}
```